# obtaining string value from Unknown elf-x86-64 binary with gdb

Tags: binary-analysis, gdb, binary, strings

I'm trying to find a string value stored in memory by a binary (possibly written in C) that won't show up when I perform "strings a.out". I have tried examining particular memory addresses of interest that I have picked out from the assembly code but with no success. Thus, I am looking to try and print all the string values stored in memory (or char* arrays) by the program. Is there a way to do this? (note: the file does not contain debugging info). Thanks!

Comment: You could, for example, run `strings` on a memory dump or the memory virtual files linux exposes.

Answer (score 3):

If the executable is not compiled statically, I think the easiest way is to inject a shared object (.so) with **LD_PRELOAD** to hook/overload the function which prints it and display the address of the buffer. If you disable ASLR, you should be able to set a memory breakpoint on the string address and then figure out how it was 'encrypted'.
Another solution is to print the return address using **__builtin_return_address**.